# What is the easiest way to play CD-Rs on my already modified Sega Saturn?

Tags: homebrew, system-mods, sega-saturn

I have a PAL model 2 Saturn that is already modified to switch between Europe, US, and Japan regions and between 50/60hz. It's controlled with the reset button so I think it's [this switchess mod](https://knzl.at/saturnmod/).

Unfortunately, it doesn't enable playing CD-Rs. Is it advisable to try and modify it further to get it to play CD-Rs or would I be best off getting an unmodified one?

What is the easiest mod for an amateur to install to play CD-Rs?

(If it makes a difference, I need to play CD-Rs because I'm trying to play the [translated version of Shining Force 3](http://sf3trans.shiningforcecentral.com/patch-instructions/)).

Comment: Just in case someone becomes overeager: For all we know, those CD-Rs might be backups of copies the OP already owns. Keep that in mind and assume good faith before flagging this as "piracy". Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @Nolonar Yes I can confirm that I have the original copies of Shining Force 3.